# boost::asio - collisions between servers, two-way communication

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm trying to write an application using ASIO that allows servers to act as clients. For example:

I have 3 servers that need to communicate between each other. They need to be able to act as clients when talking to the other servers in the network. All 3 servers can service requests via either unix domain sockets or TCP/IP with SSL.

Here is how the data flows:

1) A standalone client connects to server A(via a unix domain socket) and sends it a request.

2) Server tries to answer the request, but if it can't, it initiates a TCP/IP connection to Server B(now server A acts as a client for server B) and forwards the request to it. Server also "taints" the packet to tell server B not to forward the message to another server, so that an infinite loop isn't created.

3) Server B responds to Server A if it can process the request.

4) If Server B can process the request, Server A returns the response to the standalone client.

5) If Server B can NOT process the request, Server A tries to contact Server C, Server D, Server E, etc

This works...  UNTIL Server B which has it's own standalone client, tries to contact Server A at the same time as Server A tries to contact Server B. It creates a colision and both servers will wait indefinitely to get a response from another. Using a deadline timer I can avoid the indefinite wait, but it doesn't solve the problem.

What's the proper way to do this?

Edit: I split Server into 2 classes (Server and PeerProxy) running in separate threads but I still get a deadlock.

Here is what ive done. I've split the Unix listener and TCP listener into classes Server and PeerProxy. Server has it's own io_service, and PeerProxy has it's own too. When Server starts, it also starts PeerProxy running in a second thread(so it doesn't block execution of Server). The flow of data is like this now:

Standalone client -> Server A (can't answer) -> PeerProxy B -> Server B(got answer) -> PeerProxy B -> Server A -> Standalone client

Same problem I a deadlock when standalone client for Server B goes to PeerProxy A at the same time as Server A goes to PeerProxy B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle each request asynchronously in your servers, i.e. separate the handling into separate threads of execution. That way servers stay responsive, i.e. they can react to new requests while they are talking to other clients or servers.

So in your case, when two clients 1 and 2 are sending requests to servers A and B, that only the other server can answer (or not), the two servers might look like this:

```
Server A:                                   Server B:
Thread 0  | Thread 1     | Thread 2         Thread 0  | Thread 1     | Thread 2

listen...                                   listen...
-> req 1                                    -> req 2
listen... | handle req 1                    listen... | handle req 2
listen... | forward to B                    listen... | forward to A
-> req B  | wait...                         -> req A  | wait...
listen... | wait...        | handle req B   listen... | wait...      | reject req A  
listen... | -> B: rejected | answer req B   listen... | wait...       
listen... | forward to C                    listen... | -> A: answer       
listen... | -> C: answer                    listen... | req 2 done       
listen... | req 1 done                      listen...
listen...                                   listen...
```

Here, Thread 0 of each server has no other purpose than listening to incoming requests and spinning of other threads that handle those requests. The other threads each handle exactly one request by either answering it or forwarding it to all servers or denying it if it has been "tainted".

**Note:** Those threads do not necessarily have to be real thread objects at all. They can be sequences of ASIO async*-calls or lightweight tasks in some threading framework like TBB.

**Update:** I'll post some sceleton pseudocode  for you how I would implement the servers using Boost.Asio. To do so, I want to indroduce a little notion I found useful for understanding Asio's execution: You can see it like a state machine, where the `async_*` calls are state transitions, while the handlers are the states. Normally you have one `async_*`-call per handler execution, wich means you go from one state to one other state. If you have more than one subsequent `async_*`-call in a handler, that means that the handler is spawning secondary threads of execution. If a handler does not call any `async_*` function, the corresponding thread of execution ends.

Now to the implementation.

Thread 0 gies like the typical Asio tutorial shows, create a socket and listen for incoming connections. The only thing is that on each new client connection a new thread of execution (read: sequence of handlers) is spawned:

```
accept_handler(client connection) {
  async_read(client_request, request_handler) //spawn new thread of execution
  async_accept(next client connection, accept_handler) //transition to accept_handler
}
```

Thread N: starts with the `request_handler`:

```
request_handler(client_request) {
  if canProcess 
    async_send_answer(client, done_handler) //transition to done_handler
  else  //relay request to first server on list
    async_connect(first server on list, connect_handler) //transition to connect_handler
}
```

The `done_handler` will typically log the successful answer and *not* call another `async_*` function, meaning the connection to the client will be closed and the thread of execution ends.

The sequence of handlers for sending the request to the other servers is the typical connect-send-receive-disconnect sequence:

```
connect_handler          -- async_send(request) ---------> send_handler
send_handler             -- async_read(answer) ----------> read_handler
read_handler (no answer) -- async_connect(next server) --> connect_handler
```

that loop is ended if either an answer is received from one of the servers or if there is no more server in the list:

```
read_handler (answer ok)       -- async_send_answer(client) --> done_handler
read_handler (no more servers) -- async_send_fail(client) ----> done_handler
```

Comment: Would you be able to show me some pseudo-code or c++(ie. the Connection class, which handles the incoming connections through the async_read_some, async_write calls), to help me understand this?

Comment: How should I handle the waiting? via deadline_timer::async_wait?

Comment: waiting means waiting for a response from the server you contacted via `async_read`, listening means waiting for anew client connection via `async_accept`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, I attempted to do something similar while I was writing my initial post, but I still get a deadlock, and it's puzzling me. Here is what ive done. I've split the Unix listener and TCP listener into classes Server and PeerProxy. Server has it's own io_service, and peer proxy has it's own too. When Server starts, it also starts PeerProxy running in a second thread(so it doesn't block execution of Server). The flow of data is like this now:

Standalone client -> Server A (can't answer) -> PeerProxy B -> Server B(got answer) -> PeerProxy B -> Server A -> Standalone client

Same problem

Comment: So I discovered something that I probably shouldn't have been doing. When server A was connecting to Server B, it was using a separate io_service (not server A's ioservice). It seems to be working mostly, but sometimes I get error when connecting to another server such as: 
Peer::handle_handshake: Unable to handshake with: 10.0.3.15 - bad message type

the "bad message type" is from boost::system::error_code. What could be the reason?

Comment: @user2496228: wrt the second `io_service`, I wouldn't do that. You could use several threads calling `io_service::run` in parallel on the same `io_service`. However, you'll need to synchronize some handlers then by using strands (for example, you might not want to have server A trying to connect to server B multiple times concurrently). Wrt the "bad message type": I do not know about that error. Maybe start a new question for that one.

Comment: Second io_service, do you mean the one in PeerProxy?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple race condition.  You'd want to implement some sort of atomic lock variable or semaphor or flag, so if one server is about to send a request to another, it will from that moment reject any incoming requests from other servers.  I'd probably use std::atomic to implement this.

Comment: Atomic locks between different programs? I doubt that would be a good decision. He just hast to keep his servers repsonsive, i.e. requests should be worked on asynchronously.

Comment: The only reason to use an atomic lock in this case is to ensure that modifications of the lock themselves don't cause concurrency issues for anything reading them.  I agree that an asynchronous model would be sensible to implement here, but that's in no way mutually exclusive to the answer i gave; presumably the server should still reject requests from other servers when it itself doesn't know the answer it's being asked for.

Comment: That seems to be implemented already, i.e. the "tainted" packages (coming from another server) are not forwarded to yet other servers. So if the server cannot answer them, he has no choice but to reject them.